# C# Reverse items in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, reverse

I'm trying to reverse items in a dictionary in C#.
I have tried:

```
Dictionary<double, int> dict = new Dictionary<double, int>();
...add itmes to it....
var v = dict.Reverse()
```

However, dict.Reverse() gives me a type of IEnumberable>. I was just wondering how I could make it to a type of Dictionary?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Dictionary isn't an ordered data structure.  For Reverse to have any real meaning you'll need to use a SortedDictionary.  You can get a reversed copy of a SortedDictionary by creating a new one with a Comparer that does the opposite sorting to the original (see [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk18b2y0.aspx)).

```
var reversed = new SortedDictionary( original, new ReverseKeyComparer() );
```

Note that `ReverseKeyComparer` is a ficticious class for the example.

Also - you need to know that the SortedDictionary is somewhat of a misnomer, if you equate Dictionary to *map* or *hashtable*. It uses a binary tree implementation (Red-Black, I think) with different algorithmic complexity than the hashtable implementation of Dictionary. See the Remarks sections of their respective documentation pages. If performance is critical, you might want to consider whether the ordering is truly important.

Answer (score 15):

**Stop!**

Dictionaries and hashtables and sets have no ordering.

There is absolutely no point in sorting or changing the order.

Comment: Hahahahha +1 for **stop**. xD

Comment: This answer is funny, but @tvanfossons's is more informative.

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic: There is nothing funny about my answer. I am dead  serious.

Comment: thanks leppie, but the answer from tvanfosson is just what i was after.
thanks again.

Comment: You being serious doesn't stop this answer from being funny

Answer (score 3):

If you want dictionaries to have a certain order, you should look into SortedDictionary.
See [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)